# How do I search stackoverflow for at keywords like "@private" or "@synthesize"?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

My search arguments get stripped of the at sign.
How do I prevent that?

Comment: This is a question for meta.

Comment: Next up: "how to I search for the ++ operator?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now searches don't include the @ symbol.  Since private and synthesize are keywords even without the @ symbol, search for private and synthesize alone.

If you really need to search only for posts containing the @ symbol, use google:

[Google search `site:stackoverflow.com "@synthesize"`](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+%22@synthesize%22)

Alternately, couple them with the appropriate tags:

[Stack Overflow search: `objective-c synthesize`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=objective-c+synthesize)

Comment: The problem with searching for private instead of @private is that I get way too much noise in the search results to be useful.

Comment: @P5ycH0 I think you'll find that if you couple these keywords with the appropriate tags, such as objective-c, then you'll get the results you want.  Searching for symbols is problematic because not all answers are going to contain the symbols outside code blocks.  Many languages use these keywords, so if you're interested in a specific language, you have to narrow your results down.  I've added another suggested search that may help you out.

Comment: Thanks, your second suggestion yields much more usable results.

Answer (score 4):

[SymbolHound](http://www.symbolhound.com) is a symbol-inclusive search engine for programmers that I co-founded. Stack Overflow is currently indexed, so these arguments will not be stripped from your search and should yield relevant Stack Overflow results. For example:

- "@private" yields: http://symbolhound.com/?q=%40private
- "@synthesize" yields: http://symbolhound.com/?q=%40synthesize

Comment: It appears it [was broken in April 2022](https://stackapps.com/questions/2690/symbolhound-search-stack-overflow-for-special-characters#comment18724_2690).

Answer (score 0):

Type it into search bar with square brackets: [private] [synthesize]

Comment: searching for [private] yields no results at all !!

Comment: Square brackets is a search-by-tag, so it is not good way. For example, I'm looking for @Implements java annotation -- there is no guarantee, that for each annotation there will be corresponding tag.